# kendo-multi-select: filter-text not removed when autoClose = false

Tags: kendo-multiselect

I use kendo-multi-select at angular project.

I have set auto-select = false.

When user filter by start typing, and then he select item, the filter-text not removed.
The selected item is attached to the input and after that the typed-text appear.

Any solution?

**HTML code:**

```
 <select id="users-multiSelect" k-auto-close="false" kendo-multi-select k-rebind="$ctrl.usersOptions" k-options="$ctrl.usersOptions" k-ng-model="$ctrl.formData.users" ></select>
```

**Notice,** that in the following link I see that this is not the expected behavior.
So please don't suggest me work-around-code to remove the text by myself, but let me know the problematic-point, if you know. See the question in the link, point number 4:
https://www.telerik.com/forums/filter-doesn't-clear-on-select

Answer (score 0):

Handle the change event of the MultiSelect widget. In the event handler you can clear the text value of the input and the filter value:

```
change:function(e){
          e.sender.wrapper.find('input').val("");
          e.sender.dataSource.filter({});
        }
```